# How can we upload Blazor WebAssembly project to IIS

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Could anyone help me, it's been a week and I can't solve it.

I generated the default blazor project webassembly with .net8.0 . Compiling with visual studio works both locally and on the server
But when you put it in IIS it gives an error.
I've tried so many things that I'm almost giving up... the error message is the following

```
[message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G86um.png)
```